# get_post_thumbnail does not display thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I'm trying to get a specific post's thumbnail by using the post's ID.
I have this code snippet in my index.php file

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail(64 , 'post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-format-big' ) ); ?>
```

It doesn't return any image/thumbnail at all. Anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `echo` with [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/):

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail(64 , 'post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-format-big' ) );
```

In WordPress, a rule of thumb (no pun intended) is to use `echo` with functions prefixed with `get_`. Functions prefixed with `the_` on the other hand, display their output immediately (e.g. [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) ).

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I missed that bit! It was such an elementary mistake, thank you for the help!

Comment: Happy to help! Don't worry it happens to everybody and is more or less a rite of passage in the WP world :-)

Comment: echo with `get_` prefix and no echo with `the_` prefix`, wow didn't aware of this. Till now I used echo when the function don't work in regular way by thinking if it is not showing output then might show with echo hahaha. This is really great information to know :)